# How to configure Apache 2.4 to use ProxyPass to rewrite the websocket's port?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, websocket

My Nodejs WS ( pure Websocket, I am not using socket.io ) works on port 5000 and I wish to proxy pass to the domain itself.

I have tried to add the following lines but I still failed to get myself connected to it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/            [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:5000/$1 [P,L]

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
```

How can I `ProxyPass` port 5000 to my domain / ? and if I do, how can I get connected to wss://mydomain.com without :5000 ?